# cloning the Opportunity when the Stage is Closed Won and get the value of its Primary Campaign Source

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

When an opportunity x is updated to Stage Closed Won. I will create new Opportunity Y

with the value of Primary Campaign from Opportunity x using Process Builder.

Primary Campaign Source is a look up field

I am already ok with the other field but this is the oly that I cannot get the value of.

If this cannot be done using Process builder. Can we do this using Flow, if yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question, Could You please explain a bit more Information. However, I don't see any difficulty creating a new opp with process builder.

[image]

Comment: I already clone the Opportunity X to new Oppty Y and provided the Oppty Y with the values of Close Date, Opportunity Name ... etc... however I need to have the Primary Campaign Source  ( a look up field) set to OpptyX.Primary Campaign Source. Please let me know if you still need further information. Thanks :)

Comment: How can you set the OppId to Campaign LookUp field?  it's not possible.

Comment: The API field name of Primary Campaign Source is CampaignId.  The screenshot that amidstCloud posted shows you what you need.